# Math error when multiplying float by integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def CalculateExchange(currency2,rate):
    currencyamount1 = int(input("Enter the amount: "))
    currencyamount2 = (currencyamount1 * rate)
    print(currencyamount2,currency2)
```

When multiplying the exchange rate obtained earlier on in the program by the number inputted by the user, instead of it outputting an actual number, it just outputs the amount entered in the form of the exchange rate, e.g. when the exchange rate is 5 and the amount entered is 6 it will just output 6.6.6.6.6 , I could really use help, I know this problem probably seems quite insignificant and easy to correct but I'm having trouble trying to sort it out.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of every question ever claiming floating point math doesn't work, but voting to close as unclear because you don't even tell us what "error" you're seeing.

Comment: Or what input is necessary to get the wrong result.  There are probably some cases where python can do it correctly ...

Comment: You are multiplying a *string* by an integer; somewhere, you failed to convert your input. The code you show works fine, which is more-or-less-completely unhelpful. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. And your description is incorrect; `rate` must be the string, as the input in this function *is* converted.

Comment: I have corrected the issue, thanks to an answer by BadKarma, I failed to realize that my variables were of different types. Amateur mistake I know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to get around an error like this is to cast your int back into a float before multiplying

```
def CalculateExchange(currency2,rate):
    currencyamount1 = int(input("Enter the amount: "))
    currencyamount2 = (float(currencyamount1) * float(rate))
    print(currencyamount2,currency2)
```

Comment: @Tom1998 given that the output is `'6.6.6.6.6.'`, it sounds to me like `rate` is a string. When you multiply the string `'6.'` by the number `5`, you get that string repeated five times in a row. This answer will solve your problem by converting your string to a float first.

Answer (score 1):

Under Python 2, the function [input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) performs an [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) on the input string:

```
Python 2.7.7 (default, Jun 14 2014, 23:12:13) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x=input('Enter x: ')
Enter x: 2
>>> x
2
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
>>> x*5
10
```

And a float:

```
>>> x=input('Enter x: ')
Enter x: 2.2
>>> type(x)
<type 'float'>
>>> x*5
11.0
```

Since it is widely considered unwise to take arbitrary code from users in an application, this behavior was changed under Python 3.

Under Python 3, [input](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#input) always returns a string:

```
Python 3.4.1 (default, May 19 2014, 13:10:29) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> x=input('Enter x: ')
Enter x: 2.
>>> type(x)
<class 'str'>
```

Which explains your result:

```
>>> x*5
'2.2.2.2.2.'
```

If you want to *safely* have similar functionality in Python 3, you can wrap `input` in a call to [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> x=literal_eval(input('Enter x: '))
Enter x: 2.2
>>> x
2.2
>>> type(x)
<class 'float'>
```

Or, just convert the user input to the desired data type with `int(x)` or `float(x)`

Answer (score -5):

```
currencyamount2 = float(currencyamount1 * rate)
```