# Ensure that my code returns the actual decimal value from my calculator?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to make a calculator that takes some input from the user and print the result but when I calculate `4*7/5+3/4` it returns `5.0`. How can I fix this.

This is my code:

```
num = float(input(">>> "))
print num
```

I expected the output of `4*7/5+3/4` to be `6.35` but it returned `5.0`.

Comment: "Computer math is to math what computer music is to music." This is well discussed elsewhere on SO, as well as in the Python docs. Maybe start here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25573298/1531971 (Hint: `print 4.0*7.0/5.0+3.0/4.0`)

Comment: Note: This is [fixed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) in Py3, so you can also `from __future__ import division` which makes `/` float and `//` integer division. And you will be future proofed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are calculating with integers, so for example `4 * 7 /5` does not equal `5.6` but `5.0`.

You can solve the problem by making floats out of integers, so:

```
4.0 * 7.0 / 5.0 + 3.0 / 4.0
```